# Add System Date to file name during Oracle SQL Run

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

I am running the following code in SQL developer (oracle) to run the query and export a csv file into a folder. I would like to add the system date to the filename as well. I am using the following code. Although it does the job, it asks the user to input the date in the pop up window. I am looking to get rid of the pop up window and rather have the code use the system date instead. Is there any way i can eliminate the user input window?

Second issue is that this also brings in the SQL code to the output file along with the query results, is there any way to avoid bringing in the SQL as well?

```
set VERIFY off 
set FEEDBACK off
set echo off 
set heading off
col date_stp new_value date_stp
Select to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') date_stp from dual;

Spool 'I:\Folder\ExportData&date_stp..csv'; 
SET sqlformat csv;
Select Customer, ID, etc -- the content of the query

Spool off;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how: in order to avoid displaying the `select` statement within the spooled file, you need to

```
set term off
set feed off
```

but **not** directly in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer); you'll have to **save** the following contents into a .SQL file and run it using `@`.

So: `p.sql`

```
set term off
set feed off

col sd new_value x
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') sd from dual;

spool dept&x..txt
select * From dept;
spool off
```

Testing:

```
SQL> @p                                 --> call the .sql file
SQL> $dir *.txt
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of C:\Users\lf

12.06.2020.  21:13               494 dept20200612.txt       --> file name is OK
               1 File(s)            494 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  260.040.732.672 bytes free

SQL> $type dept20200612.txt
                                               --> no SELECT statement here
    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

In order to stop SQL*Plus or SQL Developer asking for value of a substitution variable (that's what `&something` represents), run `set define off`.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot! I added a line ```Set Define Off```. It has stopped asking for User Input by eliminating the pop up window, however it now replaces the file name with "Filename&Datum.csv". Would you know what happened? I am using the same code i posted earliar.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said: put the whole code into a .SQL script and run the script. See example I posted above.

Comment: I had to make changes to incorporate my own code, but overall essense of the sql was similar to what you recommended. Thank you so much!